# Automatically restart Selenium grid on timeout

Tags: selenium-grid

Is there a way to automatically restart Selenium grid on a timeout? When one of the Remote Controls in our build environment times out on a page, the whole Selenium system has to restart. I have to restart the Selenium grid hub and then go to each remote control and restart it separately. Seems like there should be a way that a timeout on a remote control can be sent as a notification to the grid hub and it could restart. Then on each remote control, if they were no longer in communication with the hub, they could try restarting themselves.
Do I just have to wait for Grid hub 1.0.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium Grid 1.0.5 has an integrated watchdog that restarts workers that time out.  Likewise, the workers will re-register themselves with the hub, even if the hub is restarted.  So, that should take care of the bulk of your problems.

Comment: I've now upgraded us to 1.0.7 and it is incredible to realize that I haven't had to restart our hub and all the remote controls for over 2 weeks now.